# Поиск ненулевой ячейки в блоке памяти

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

> Составить программу, которая находит первый ненулевой элемент в заданном блоке памяти из пяти байтовых элементов. Смещение начального адреса блока берется из регистра ВХ, смещение конечного адреса блока берется из регистра DI. Смещение адреса ненулевого байта возвращается в регистре ВХ. Если ненулевой байт не найден, то по возвращении в регистре ВХ будет содержаться то же значение, что и в DI . использовать команду JNZ.

В самом коде я задала массив и сделала цикл в котором я к регистру si добавляла 1, пока он не найдёт ненулевой элемент. И в коде где то должна быть команда **lea**, но я не понимаю зачем она и что с ней делать и в том что я не могу вывести значение регистра si, посоветуйте что-либо.

```
data segment para public "data"
a db 1,3,0,7,5
mes db 10,13,'Stroka- $'
data ends
stk segment stack
db 256 dup ("?")
stk ends
code segment para public "code"
start:
assume ds:data, cs:code, ss:stk
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov si,0
mov di,0
mov cl,5
mov ch,0

m1:

mov al,a[si]
inc si
inc di
dec cl
cmp al,ch
jnz m1

mov ah,09
mov dx,offset mes
int 21h


mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: А зачем вам SI. У вас же в BX адрес есть. Если его там вдруг нет, то тогда и нужна lea, что бы его туда загрузить. Так что прямо по [BX] и проверяйте байты и увеличивайте его, пока он не достигнет DI

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который у вас на данный момент получился.

Comment: И укажите какой именно ассемблер используете (tasm, masm или может быть fasm?)

Comment: @PashsPash, он же вроде вставил код

Comment: @Grundy, код вставлен 18 минут назад, а вопрос закрыт 2 часа назад. Можете проголосовать за переоткрытие, если хотите. Я уже проголосовал)

Comment: @Mike lea bx,a   mob di,5   mov ch,0   И тогда в метке будет тоже самое только будет inc bx   dec di   cmp al,ch?И как мне вывести на экран первый ненулевой элемент?

Comment: @Nastya, по условию у вас начало массива хранится в `bx`, а на выходе адрес ненулевого байта тоже в `bx`. Логично `bx` и использовать как регистр-счетчик в цикле (вместо `si`). `lea bx, a` примерно то же самое что `mov bx, offset a`, но `lea` позволяет выполнять еще некоторые арифметические операции.

Comment: Еще, код выполняющий задачу из условия лучше оформить в виде процедуры, а остальное - просто инициализация регистров, вызов процедуры и вывод результата. Если вам известны инструкции `call` и `ret`, то можно так и реализовать в виде процедуры. По поводу вывода - нужно где-то нагуглить код вывода регистра в 16-ричном виде на экран и применить его в своей программе.

Comment: Зачем цикл для поиска? Чем не угодил `repe scas`?

Answer (score 1):

Задачу из вопроса лучше реализовать в виде процедуры. Это позволяет абстрагироваться от подготовки данных, от вывода результата, просто нужно написать код, который соответствует спецификации - что получаем на входе, что должно быть на выходе.

Процедура может выглядеть так (считаем, что адрес из регистра `DI` не принадлежит блоку данных, иначе как определить, что первый ненулевой элемент не найден, а не находится в последнем элемента):

```
proc1:
    ; На входе в BX - адрес начала блока данных, в DI - адрес конца блока
m1:
    cmp bx, di ; проверяем условие выхода
    jge ex

    mov al, [bx]
    test al, al  ; проверяем текущий элемент на 0 (для простоты можно заменить на cmp al, 0)
    jnz ex ; выход если не 0
    inc bx
    jmp m1
ex:
    ; при выходе из цикла как раз получается, что в BX адрес нулевого элемента или BX = DI, если такой элемент не найден
    ret
```

Данная процедура просто решает поставленную задачу без привязки к вызывающему коду или к коду выводящему результат. Но для демонстрации работы также нужен код инициализации и код вывода.

Процедура перевода числа в регистре `bx` в шестнадцатеричный вид (результат в буфере `buf`):

```
tohex:
    mov di, 3
th0:
    mov si, bx
    and si, 0Fh
    mov cl, [chars+si]
    mov [buf+di], cl
    ror bx, 4 ; Циклический битовый поворот числа. После 4 поворотов по 4 бита BX станет таким же как был
    dec di
    jns th0 ; Если не отрицательное число, повторить
    
    ret

; В секцию данных
buf db '0000$'
chars db '0123456789ABCDEF'
```

Полный код:

```
data segment para public "data"

a db 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0 ; По условию ищем первый ненулевой элемент, поэтому сначала идут нули, потом ненулевой элемент
a_end: ; Конец блока данных, этот адрес нужно поместить в регистр DI

buf db '0000$'
chars db '0123456789ABCDEF'

data ends

stk segment stack
db 256 dup ("?")
stk ends

code segment para public "code"
assume ds:data, cs:code, ss:stk

proc1:
    ; На входе в BX - адрес начала блока данных, в DI - адрес конца блока
m1:
    cmp bx, di ; проверяем условие выхода
    jge ex

    mov al, [bx]
    test al, al  ; проверяем текущий элемент на 0 (для простоты можно заменить на cmp al, 0)
    jnz ex ; выход если не 0
    inc bx
    jmp m1
ex:
    ; при выходе из цикла как раз получается, что в BX адрес нулевого элемента или BX = DI, если такой элемент не найден
    ret


tohex:
    ; Переводим число из регитра BX в шестнадцатеричное представление, результат в буфере buf
    mov di, 3
th0:
    mov si, bx
    and si, 0Fh
    mov cl, [chars+si]
    mov [buf+di], cl
    ror bx, 4 ; Циклический битовый поворот числа. После 4 поворотов по 4 бита BX станет таким же как был
    dec di
    jns th0 ; Если не отрицательное число, повторить
    
    ret


start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    mov bx, offset a ; или lea bx, a
    mov di, offset a_end ; или lea di, a_end
    call proc1
    
    call tohex

    mov ah,09
    mov dx,offset buf
    int 21h

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Вывод:

```
0004
```

т.е. по смещению 4 от начала сегмента данных находится первый ненулевой элемент массива `a`, что и требовалось получить.

Скриншотик (выполнялось под DosBox):

[image: Скриншот]

По поводу инструкции `lea`. В простейшем случае `lea bx, a` эквивалентно `mov bx, offset a`. Но кроме получения адреса (смещения) `lea` позволяет выполнять адресную арифметрику. Например, если нам нужно не записать в регистр значение элемента массива (например, как в вашем коде `mov al, a[si]`), а просто вычислить это смещение и положить в регистр, то можно записать `lea ax, a[si]`. Это удобно например когда у вас переменные не глобальные, а локальные, и их адреса считаются относительно регистра `bp`, например как `word ptr [bp+4]`, и вам нужно передать адрес переменной в процедуру, тогда просто с помощью `lea` записываете адрес в регистр, а дальше уже как-то передаете этот адрес в процедуру.